# how to call oracle procedure that has in out cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have this procedure and I want to know how to execute it in PL/SQL. Can someone please help me?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "P_TEST" 
 (
    c$inchidere  IN OUT  softys.pk_utils.GenericCursor,
    p_OLD IN   empl.code%type,
    p_NEW IN   empl.code%type,
    p_NXT IN   empl.code%type,
    p_ORGID IN   empl.ORGID%type
  )
is
begin
    open c$inchidere  for
        select
     ...

end
```

Comment: That depends on the client you want to use. PL/SQL? Toad? JDBC call? Unix shell script?

Comment: I use PL/SQL :)

Comment: `softys.pk_utils.GenericCursor` looks like a legacy definition from back before Oracle provided `sys_refcursor` in 10.2. If so I'd want to get rid of it to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a procedure in PL/SQL is easy. The tricky part is reading the REF CURSOR. We need to fetch it into variables or a record type which *match the projection of the executed query*. That your code uses something called `softys.pk_utils.GenericCursor` makes me think you might have problems with that bit.

Anyway, this example presumes the result set returns a single numeric column. You will need to adjust the target variables to match the actual projection.

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
    l_id number;
begin

    P_TEST (
       c$inchidere  => rc,
      p_OLD => 'whatever',
      p_NEW => 'meh',
      p_NXT => 'ABC',
      p_ORGID => 123456  );
    loop
        fetch rc into l_id;
        exit when rc%notfound;
    end loop;
end;
```

Not sure why the ref cursor parameter is defined as IN OUT. As you open it immediately it only needs to be OUT.

Comment: If an answer is right for you, please accept it; This is both a way to mark the question as closed and to say thanks to people who helped you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more on what to do when someone answers you.